# How to change the priority from windows 10 to ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, grub2, windows-10

I am using windows 10 and ubuntu 14.04 as dual boot in my Lenovo think pad, I would  like to know how i could possibly prioritize ubuntu over windows 10, when i restart my system i cannot login into ubuntu since i have set up Windows 10 as my default boot in , how could i possibly change it?.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Windows Boot Manager, in Windows, search for **msconfig**, and use it to set the desired default. You can also install **BCDedit** (Google it) and edit the boot menu that way.

If you're using grub, in terminal, type **sudo gedit /etc/default/grub** and change the line **GRUB_DEFAULT=** to equal the name or the number (starting at 0) of the desired OS. To find the exact name for a given OS, in terminal, type **grep menuentry /boot/grub/grub.cfg**.

Cheers, Al

Comment: Continuing from your mention of GRUB, I love the [GRUB Customizer](https://launchpad.net/grub-customizer) tool. It's a bit old, but it does the trick and provides a fairly easy to use GUI for editing those same files. It also let me add a background picture to the menu!

Comment: I've only heard bad things about GRUB Customizer. Cheers, Al

Comment: Interesting. I've never had an issue with it. Experiences vary I suppose.